# Asset Precompile on the development machine before capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I want the asset precompile to happen on my dev machine beofore the code is packed (tar ball'ed) by capistrano and have the precompiled assets already included in the final deployment package.

When I try the inbuilt capistrano recipe thats in 
`load 'deploy/assets'` it runs 
 `rake RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile` on the server.

The reason I am  looking for this because at the moment the precompile is taking too long on my EC2 micro-instance (and also at times just hangs), 
It would great if asset compile could be done even before the deploy starts so that I can save the server from this heavy duty work load - until at least I have better configured servers available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workflow is still a little bumpy at the moment, but you may find some success using [Guard-Rails-Assets](https://github.com/dnagir/guard-rails-assets). It's a little slow, especially if you are making a lot of asset changes, but it will compile assets when they are changed and you can just check them in to your repo to be deployed later.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach :)

Answer (score 3):

I've just written a gem to solve this problem inside Rails, called [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3). It speeds up your `assets:precompile` by only recompiling changed files, and only compiling once to generate all assets. It works out of the box for Capistrano, since your assets directory is shared between releases.

It would be really awesome if you could help me test out the [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) gem, and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: +1 Nathan, thats indeed great piece of work. Will surely get this added on to my project and let you'll know. and then may be consider switching the accepted answer :)

Comment: Nathan, this did not work for me. I kept getting "undefined method `digest' for nil:NilClass", would you like me to provide any specifics so that we can nail this? I will file an issue at github as well

Comment: Hi @thanikkal, thanks for your feedback! Please update the gem to the latest version and try again, I think it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! That was quick! really quick!!! I am able to precompile assets without the error. Will validate during the next deployment. If you are still here just want to confirm  (may be a dumb question to ask), this would take care of the assets even inside Engines as well as .erb asset templates as well right?

Comment: Hi, no problem! Yep, this will definitely take care of all assets, no matter if they are in your project directory or from a gem. It will always process .erb files, and handle @imports for SASS and Less

Comment: Great! just what the doctor ordered!

Comment: @nathan.f77 Your gem is terrific. Also, kudos for the work you did for the changes you brought to Capistrano in how it deploys assets.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `load 'deploy/assets'` from `Capfile` or `config/deploy.rb`, and add the following lines to the `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :assets_role, [ :web, :app ]
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
set :assets_tar_path, "#{release_name}-assets.tar.gz"

before "deploy:update" do
  run_locally "rake assets:precompile"
  run_locally "cd public; tar czf #{Dir.tmpdir}/#{assets_tar_path} assets"
end

before "deploy:finalize_update", :roles => assets_role, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  upload "#{Dir.tmpdir}/#{assets_tar_path}", "#{shared_path}/#{assets_tar_path}"
  run "cd #{shared_path}; /bin/tar xzf #{assets_tar_path}"
  run "/bin/ln -s #{shared_path}/assets #{release_path}/public"
  run "/bin/rm #{shared_path}/#{assets_tar_path}"
end
```

If you use [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3), add this to the last block:

```
  run "cd #{release_path}; #{rake} assets:clean_expired 2> /dev/null"
```