# Asset compilation taking a lot of time - around 10-15 mins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, ruby-enterprise-edition

I don't know it's just me, or everybody is facing same kinda issue. I am trying to precompile assets on server with this command -

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

but it takes about 10mins to compile all assets. The project is  not big, its just started and has some 5 coffee script files, 3 css files.

Because of this, even capistrano deployments takes longer to complete.

Earlier it was ruby 1.9.2 there, now I am trying with REE 1.8.7.

Comment: @rtdp might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258336/asset-precompile-on-the-development-machine-before-capistrano-deployment and this http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2538285